# Make recursive chmod faster

Tags: linux, chmod

I have an installation script that `unzip`s a directory, then recursively `chmod`s its contents.

I'm surprised it takes almost 10 times the time it takes to unzip, to run the following two commands:

```
find $dir -type f -exec chmod a+r "{}" \;
find $dir -type d -exec chmod a+rx "{}" \;
```

Am I doing something wrong, is there a faster way to change the chmod of all files and directories?

Comment: One trick I use is just to do a chmod -R on everything (files & directories) then run the find to fix up the directories

Comment: You are doing `-exec chmod a+r "{}" \;` try `chmod a+r "{}" +` instead.  The first will run the command chmod once for every directory.  The later command will run chmod a few times, with a list of directories as options (ie `chmod dir1 dir2 dir3 dir4`).  This means far few processes are created.

Comment: Could the downvoter/closer explain what's wrong with this question?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but your question probably would have been more appropriate over on unix.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @Zoredache Woah, the `+` trick is blazing fast! Can you add your comment as an answer?

Comment: You can try `-exec chmod a+r "{}" + \;` too, that should be faster. Duh, I'm too slow.

Comment: @jeffatrackaid no fixup needed, see [mgorven’s answer](http://serverfault.com/a/509373/82614)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can get rid of the `find` commands by using chmod's `X` flag:

```
execute/search only if the file is a directory or already has execute permission for some user (X)
```

This allows you to set the same permissions on files and directories, with directories additionally being executable, with a single command:

```
$ chmod -R a+rX $dir
```

Comment: Now that's a fast alternative! Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 5):

You could do the following (assumming Linux):

```
cd $dir
chmod -R a+r .
find . -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod a+x
```

This should be much faster than the combination of the two commands you indicated in your question.

Answer (score 2):

Use `tar` instead. Specifically with the `-p, --preserve-permissions, --same-permissions` flag.
You won't can't directly zip it, but `-z, --gzip`, `-j, --bzip2` or `-J, --xz` ought to work well enough. If you really must have zip it's only a `|` away.

Answer (score 0):

Given your command, I'm thinking you are spending time waiting for find not chmod.

Try:

```
chmod -R a+r $dir
```

The "-R" means recursive

When you run the unzip and other commands preface them with

```
time
```

To get a measurement of the time spent for the various commands.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately this solves only half of the problem (I need a different `chmod` for directories).